# Carbon VS Objective-C & intel-based mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-carbon

Is it possible to develop carbon application in objective-C, moreover what if i don't have a power PC based mac and i have an intel-based mac, can i still develop applications for Carbon?

Regards.

Comment: why would you want to do it? Objective-c is really powerful and cocoa has all that you need to develop application on mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely develop Carbon applications on an Intel Mac. 
Right now the biggest restriction on Carbon is that you cannot compile to a 64 bit binary. Additionally, new OS X features may or may not be available to Carbon programs.

Carbon seems to be here to stay for a while longer at least; one significant issue keeping it around is that a lot of it is available for Windows and therefore needed for iTunes development. A lot of people think that it will me deprecated in one or two more major OS X versions, though.

Comment: but my main question is that is it possible to program in objective-C?

Comment: Yes as Carbon is a C language binding and objective C is a superset of C. However why would you Cocoa is the way going forward as Apple are not providing the 64 bit version of Carbon. (and can be argued a better way)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it would be no different from programming in straight C, since Carbon is a C-based API. (In fact, you *would* be programming in straight C, and pretending the Objective-C additions don't exist.)

Moreover, Carbon is doomed. Someday, it will not exist in then-current Mac OS X. Then your application will not run. Why not use Cocoa? Then your application will not be relying on a doomed framework. Besides, I tell you from experience that Cocoa is *much* easier than Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Xcode 3.1 has templates for Carbon apps and will generate code for Intel and ppc.

Xcode 3.2 (under OSX 10.6) does not have the Carbon templates but will generate code for 32 bit PPC
see email re new Xcode [email from apple on apple developers list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Aug/msg00413.html)
As setfanB says why use Carbon now any new app should start with Cocoa

Answer (score 0):

You can still program in C even if you're writing a Cocoa application. Bear in mind that Objective-C is still a superset of C, so as long as you have whatever minimal application code needed to bootstrap (such as the templates that come with XCode) then you can write whatever C functions that you want.

(Don't know why you'd want to do that though ...)